# CSS Text carousel with fixed text

Tags: html, css, text, carousel

I am trying to recreate a effect found on [this page](https://pageproof.com/)

I searched the web and found something and try to adjust it. But i can't figure out how to align that the text to look like in the example. 
I am trying to modify the example but if there is a better practice that u can show me that's even better.
Some help to find documentation about it would be apprenticed to.

```css
 html,
body {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}

.slider {
  height: 320px;
  width: 680px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: 0%;
}

.mask {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 320px;
}

.slider ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.slider li {
  width: 680px;
  height: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -325px;
  list-style: none;
}

.slider .quote {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-style: italic;
}


.slider li.anim1 {
  -moz-animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim2 {
  -moz-animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim3 {
  -moz-animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim4 {
  -moz-animation: cycle4 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle4 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle4 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim5 {
  -moz-animation: cycle5 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle5 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle5 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider:hover li {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  4% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  16% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  21% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  92% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  96% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle2 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  16% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  24% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  36% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  41% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle3 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  36% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  44% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  56% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  61% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle4 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  56% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  64% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  76% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  81% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle5 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  76% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  84% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  96% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  4% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  16% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  21% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  50% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  92% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  96% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle2 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  16% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  24% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  36% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  41% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle3 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  36% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  44% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  56% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  60% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  61% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle4 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  56% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  64% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  76% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  81% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle5 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  76% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  84% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  96% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>
           infinite loop carousel(vertical)
        </title>
        <style>
          
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p>review 
        
        <span>
        <div class="content-slider">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="mask">
      <ul>
        <li class="anim1">
   <div class="quote">PDF's</div>
        </li>
        <li class="anim2">
          <div class="quote">Prints</div>
          
        </li>
        <li class="anim3">
          <div class="quote">Pictures</div>
          
        </li>
        <li class="anim4">
          <div class="quote">colors</div>
          
        </li>
        <li class="anim5">
          <div class="quote">testtest</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
          
        </span></p>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just position absolute the `review` text on the left side of the slider ? ( that would be one option )

Also you had some span tags and unclosed tags in your html. Please verify it it first

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}
.leftText {
position:absolute;
left:0;
}
.slider {
  height: 320px;
  width: 680px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: 0%;
}

.mask {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 320px;
}

.slider ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.slider li {
  width: 680px;
  height: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -325px;
  list-style: none;
}

.slider .quote {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-style: italic;
}


.slider li.anim1 {
  -moz-animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim2 {
  -moz-animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim3 {
  -moz-animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim4 {
  -moz-animation: cycle4 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle4 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle4 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim5 {
  -moz-animation: cycle5 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: cycle5 15s linear infinite;
  animation: cycle5 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider:hover li {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  4% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  16% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  21% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  92% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  96% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle2 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  16% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  24% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  36% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  41% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle3 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  36% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  44% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  56% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  61% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle4 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  56% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  64% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  76% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  81% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle5 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  76% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  84% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  96% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  4% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  16% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  21% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  50% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  92% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  96% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle2 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  16% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  24% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  36% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  41% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle3 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  36% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  44% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  56% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  60% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  61% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle4 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  56% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  64% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  76% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  81% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle5 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  76% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  84% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  96% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>
           infinite loop carousel(vertical)
        </title>
        <style>
          
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p class="leftText">review</p>
        
       
        <div class="content-slider">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="mask">
      <ul>
        <li class="anim1">
   <div class="quote">PDF's</div>
        </li>
        <li class="anim2">
          <div class="quote">Prints</div>
          
        </li>
        <li class="anim3">
          <div class="quote">Pictures</div>
          
        </li>
        <li class="anim4">
          <div class="quote">colors</div>
          
        </li>
        <li class="anim5">
          <div class="quote">testtest</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
          
        </span></p>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: And  how should i change it position?

Comment: well you can change it's position however you want :) with `left` `right` `top` `bottom` , translateX , translateY etc.